# Looking for a customizable horizontal accordion script using jQuery

Tags: jquery, accordion, customization

Does anyone know of a jQuery script for a horizontal accordion that allows for varied-width panels when collapsed? The site http://www.royalalberthall.com/ has the functionality I'm looking for, but uses Scriptaculous/Prototype. Would prefer to use jQuery.

I found a similar, pure JS version, but am unsure how I might change it to get different sized collapsed panels. I set [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/PEsyD/1/) up at JSFiddle, so if anyone wants to tinker, please do.

Any help or suggestions is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at [jQuery Tools](http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tabs/accordion-custom.html)

this is a code sample from their site:

```
<div id="accordion">

<h2 class="current">First pane</h2>
<div class="pane" style="display:block">... pane content ...</div>

<h2>Second pane</h2>
<div class="pane">... pane content ...</div>

<h2>Third pane</h2>
<div class="pane">... pane content ...</div>

</div>
```

Now, I haven't tried this but there's no reason why their approach shouldn't work even if you define different widths for each "tab" through css, so the first div could be `<div class="pane large">...</div>`,
the second wone `<div class="pane small">...</div>`, etc.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I'll give this a shot and let ya know how it goes.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think that jQuery Tools one will work the way I'd like it to. Thanks for the suggestion tho!

Comment: Pity. But the css principle should work with most accordion plugins.

Comment: @jflo - have you managed to find an accordion that suits your needs?